# Каково происхождение слов гурман, гуру, жюри?

Tags: этимология

Мы оба на минуту замолчали. К счастию, в эту минуту подали boeuf brasé, который был какой-то такой необыкновенный, что даже я, человек от природы неприхотливый, вознегодовал и забыл о «подтягиваниях». Но, к удивлению, Феденька, которого я считал изнеженным и гурме (я даже удивился, что встретился с ним… в Летнем саду!), не только не возмутился, но преисправно рубил ножом эту обугленную доску и проглатывал один за другим отрубленные куски. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Круглый год]
Я уже знала, что слово «гурмэ» по французски означает  попросту обжора, а вовсе не «гурман», под которым мы понимаем тонкого ценителя еды. [Е. Чекулаева. Земля людей. Полчаса до счастья // «Вокруг света», 1997]
Он был гурман, все стихи казались ему плохими. [В. Ф. Панова. Спутники (1945)]
Цитаты из Нацкорпуса показывают, что в русском языке слова гурме и гурман сблизились по своему значению.
Прежде всего, гурман (гурме) это любитель и ценитель изысканных блюд и, стало быть - знаток, эксперт, критик в области гастрономии. Кроме того, гурманом могут назвать тонкого ценителя искусства.
Выдающегося специалиста (эксперта, учителя, наставника) в определенной области знаний или вида искусств нередко величают словом «гуру».
Судейскую коллегию конкурса научно - технологических (архитектурных / музыкальных / театральных) проектов составленную из самых авторитетных профессионалов своего дела принято называть словом «жюри».
Напрашивается предположение, что «жюри» это форма слова «гуру» во множественном числе.
Можно ли в словах: гурме, гурман, гуру, жюри выделить общую основу (корень) или в этом нет смысла, потому как все имеющиеся совпадения надуманы или случайны?

Comment: Нет, "гуру" из санскрита. Остальные из французского. Это всё прекрасно можно посмотреть хотя бы в [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/гуру).

Comment: Согласен с Вашим выводом в самом конце. Замечу, что "жюри" во французский попало из английского и имеет "юридические" корни.

Comment: @grizzly А по-моему наоборот - в английский из старофранцузского. [Jury](https://www.google.com/search?q=etymology+jury&client=opera&ei=aefOYPafFfHIgwfXk7GABg&oq=jury+etimo&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIICAAQFhAKEB46BQgAEJECOgsILhDHARCvARCRAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOggILhCxAxCDAToOCC4QxwEQrwEQkQIQkwI6CAguEMcBEK8BOgUILhCxAzoCCAA6BwguELEDEEM6CgguELEDEIMBEEM6CwguEMcBEKMCEJECOgcIABCxAxBDOgsILhCxAxDHARCvAToFCAAQsQM6AgguOgYIABAWEB5Q0KO0AVj_xrQBYNvXtAFoAHACeACAAZMBiAHTB5IBAzkuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

Comment: @tum_ Нет не наоборот. Но в чём-то Вы правы: сначала из ст.фр. в англ., потом уже оттуда обратно во французский. (Смотрю фундаментальный семитомный этимологический словарь 1982 г., выпущенный НАН УССР).

Comment: @grizzly эх, такой бы словарь да в онлайн доступ...

Comment: @tum_ Его можно найти на Либгене по запросу "мельничук словник". Но только он на украинском языке — со всеми вытекающими последствиями :)

Comment: Имя христианского святого Георгий (Гюргий, Юрий) схоже по звучанию с санскритским «гуру».

Comment: Французское conjurer - колдовать, adjurer – заклинать, jurer – клясться, присягать, ругать (в русском, этому слову соответствует синоним "журить").

Comment: Жюри должно быть не только компетентным, но и беспристрастным, непредвзятым. Возможно, что членам жюри вменялось в обязанность «присягать» и «клясться» в своей «беспристрастности». В английском «perjury» – лжесвидетельство.